# how to execute cmd commands and compile it in a .bat file

Tags: batch-file, cmd

Hello I'm getting sick from repeating commands in the cmd window so I want a .bat file that makes cmd opens then execute the command, and would be great if it's closed after executing the commands like example:

```
ipconfig/release
ipconfig/renew
```

Then closes the cmd window

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Easy:
Put both commands in a text file, name it "new.bat".
Add a `@echo off` and a `exit`, and you are done:

```
@echo off
ipconfig/release
ipconfig/renew
exit
```

Every time, when you enter `new`, it will execute these commands.

And you can even do it with a double-click in WindowsExplorer.

You could save the .bat file to the desktop, so you can reach it easy with your mouse.